# VM don´t uses Graphicscard

Tags: graphics

I wand to play a linux game (64bit version of Kerbal Space Program), but i don´t wand to install it because i don´t wand to format my harddrive. I use VMWarePlayer and Ubuntu, but it seams that it´s not using my real (phisical) grafik-cart, wath can i do? Is there an VM that can use the hardware or is there a easy way to intall Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Most virtual machine softwares emulate hardware with the exception of the cpu. Some such as Vmware Player allow you to connect usb devices. You can install VMware Tools to get some graphics support for gaming within a VM, but it won't be stellar, so use low resolutions, and put the VM on the fastest storage device you have.

Alternatively Parrallels Workstation Extreme is a VM program that allows the connection of pci-e devices to a vm, including graphics cards, however you will then need 2 physical cards. 1 for the host, and 1 for the vm. It's also extremely expensive.

If you have a non UEFI version of windows such as XP or Windows 7 you can use an outdated version of Ubuntu with WUBI to install Ubuntu into a file on your windows partition. The ubuntu install will boot as a native Operating system, but no paritioning is needed, and you can uninstall/install it from inside windows.